# jquery popup always shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup

Hi I'm trying to create a cookie after the popup is shown on the page load, but somehow the popup is still showing up because in my opinion the cookies don't create. Can anybody tell me why is this happening and where is my mistake?

So here is my popup.js file content

```
//SETTING UP OUR POPUP
//0 means disabled; 1 means enabled;
var popupStatus = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup(){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup(){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup(){
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    //centering
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}
//---------------cookies-------------------//

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
alert(c_value);
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("shoppingKatalog");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
    alert(username);
  }
else 
  {
    //centering with css
    centerPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();    
    setCookie("shoppingKatalog","istekuva-za-eden-den",321);
  }
}

//--------------end cookies---------------//


//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){

    checkCookie();
    //LOADING POPUP
    //Click the button event!
    $("#button").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });

    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Click out event!
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
            disablePopup();
        }
    });

});
```

and my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>yensdesign.com - How to create a stuning and smooth popup in jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/templates/it_theshop/popup/general.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/templates/it_theshop/popup/popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
        <a href="http://www.yensdesign.com"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Go to yensdesign.com"/></a>
    </center>
    <div id="popupContact">
        <div id="popup_wrap" style="background-image:url('http://www.mywebsite.com/templates/it_theshop/images/popup/shopping-popup1.jpg');height:380px;width:800px;">
<div style="float:left;width:490px;padding:5px;">
<h1 style="margin:0px;">Заштеди до <span style="color:#981A32;">90%</span></h1>
<h2 style="margin:0px;">Имајте ја информацијата - <span style="color:#981A32;">ПРВИ!</span></h2>
<p style="margin:0px;">Дознај каде може да добиеш огромен попуст на чевли, облека, накит, козметика, производи за дома, услуги, патувања... Се она што го плаќаш во секојдневниот живот.</p>
<h4 style="margin:0px;">Нашиот Newsletter е БЕСПЛАТЕН!</h4>
<form method="post">

<table class="acymailing_form">
<p style="color:#981A32;margin:0px;">Одберете ја типот на информација што сакате да ја добивате:</p>
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="checkbox" class="acymailing_checkbox" name="subscription[]" checked="checked" value="1" /><b style="color:#981A32;">СИТЕ ПОПУСТИ И ПРОИЗВОДИ</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="checkbox" class="acymailing_checkbox" name="subscription[]" value="2" />
<b style="color:#981A32;">САМО НОВИ ПРОИЗВОДИ</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="checkbox" class="acymailing_checkbox" name="subscription[]" value="4" /><b style="color:#981A32;">САМО ПОПУСТИ</b></td>
</tr>
<tr style="color:#981A32;">
<td><label for="user_name">Име</label><input id="user_name" type="text" name="user[name]" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color:#981A32;"><label for="user_email">E-мејл</label><input id="user_email" type="text" name="user[email]" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div style="display:none;"><label for="user_html">Добивај</label></div></td>
<td><div style="display:none;"><input type="radio" name="user[html]" value="0" id="user_html_0" /><label for="user_html_0">Text</label></div><div style="display:none;"><input type="radio" name="user[html]" value="1" id="user_html_1" checked="checked" /><label for="user_html_1">HTML</label></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<div style="display:none;">
<input type="radio" name="task" value="optin" checked="checked" id="optin" /><label for="optin">Subscribe</label>
<input type="radio" name="task" value="optout" id="opftout" /><label for="optout">Unsubscribe</label> </div>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Пријави се БЕСПЛАТНО!" name="Submit" style="color: white;background-color: orange;border: 0;border-radius: 5px;height: 30px;font-weight: bold;margin-top:5px;" onclick="setCookie('mywebsite','istekuva-za-godina',364);" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="gtask" value="sub" style="color:#981A32;" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.mywebsite.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_acymailing" />
<input type="hidden" name="visiblelists" value="1,2,4" />
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenlists" value="YOUR_LISTS" />
</form>
</div>
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/templates/it_theshop/images/popup/popust.png" style="float:right;padding-right:-10px;position: absolute;margin-left: 260px;" />
</div>
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure `http://www.mywebsite.com/templates/it_theshop/popup/popup.js` has no bugs reported about this? Is it 100% solid?

Comment: @BerkerYüceer it's my own file

Comment: I can see that thats why i asked are you sure ur js file works correctly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cookie is created. Because in your function checkCookie() there you are using

```
if (username!=null && username!="")
{
 alert(username);
}
```

Here condition is not equals to null. So the cookie is created

Answer (score 0):

The popup is showing because it is not hidden by default. Try to keep it hidden by css :

```
#backgroundPopup { display:none }
```

That should hide it initially and then show it when required.

Comment: its hidden, the parameter is in the css file that i didnt include

Comment: Your code, without alerts working : http://pastebin.com/xxZyPABP popup shows on first load and thereafter does not show and a cookie is created.